# Error al clonar Div con Select2

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy tratando de clonar que contenga un id distinto para que me funcione el select2 pero me sale un error, con que no encuentra el id. Esta es la linea exactamente que me salta el error al momento de tratar de duplicar document.getElementById("select"+i+"_select2").outerHTML=""

```html
<div class="row box first" id="row_examenes">
                                        <div class="box-header">
                                            <h3><strong>2</strong>Datos de paciente: </h3>
                                            <p>Ingresa los datos del o los pacientes y los exámenes a realizar:</p>
                                            <button clas="btn btn-info" onclick="addRow()">Ingresar nuevos pacientes</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input id="username" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Enter Full Name" type="text" data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s.]+$" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input id="email" class="form-control" id="txtinput" name="email" placeholder="Enter VALID EMAIL and check the result" type="email" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input id="phone" class="form-control" id="txtinput" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone e.g.: +363012345" type="text" data-parsley-pattern="^\+{1}[0-9]+$"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <select class="js-example-basic-multiple chosen-select" name="states[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;" id="select0">
                                                <?php 
                                                    include './configuracion.php';
                                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM example";
                                                    $ans = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
                    
                                                    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ans) ){
                    
                                                        $name = $row['Examen'];
                                                        $value = $row['Value'];
                    
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $value ?>" <?php echo $name ?></option>
                                                <?php }?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div clas="row box" id="clone"></div>
```

Y este es el JavaScript con el que trato de clonar todo el div, y haciendo que me lo clone en un div que cree mas abajo

```js
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
            });
            
            var i = 0;
            var prev = 0;
            function addRow(){
                  var clone = $("#row_examenes").clone()
                clone.find("#txtinput"+prev).attr("id", "txtinput"+i);
                clone.find("#select"+prev).attr("id", "select"+i);
                clone.find("#select"+prev+"_select2").attr("id", "select"+i+"_select2");
                clone.appendTo($("#clone"));
                document.getElementById("select"+i+"_select2").outerHTML=""
                $myid = $('#select' + i);
                $myid.show().select2();
                i++;
                prev++;                  
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Pero prev e i son iguales eso no debería funcionar. Inicializa var i =1;

Comment: @Yussef lo cambie y nada que me funciona, me sigue saliendo el error